# How to remove sub string from string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this string:

```
27/06/2016
```

or:

```
15/10/2005
```

I need to convert the string above to this:

```
27/06/16
```

or

```
15/10/05
```

How can I implement it in Javascript?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple string manipulation methods:

```
function shortDate(str) 
{
    return str.substring(0, 6) + str.substring(8, 10);
}

var dt = shortDate('27/06/2016');
// returns 27/06/16
```

Comment: I was halfway through typing a near identical solution when this appeared!

Answer (score 3):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is the best library to use for date manipulation, it does this easily:

```
moment('15/10/2005', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('DD/MM/YY');
```

Comment: this is really good, when you need time manipulations often, and don't have too many js files, coz adding extra 20kb load to your page is somewhat heavy thing. cheers

Comment: and still this is beautiful solution

Answer (score 2):

Using Regular Expressions

```
/(?!.*\/)../
```

- https://regex101.com/r/tV3mA5/1

---

```
str.replace(/(?!.*\/)../,'')
```

- https://jsfiddle.net/dmj12oge/

Comment: This doesn't work. Try 10/12/2016, or any day in February.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the date is valid you can use this function

```
function formatDate (input) {
    var datePart = input.match(/\d+/g);
    year = datePart[2].substring(2); // get only two digits
    month = datePart[1];
    day = datePart[0];
    return day+'/'+month+'/'+year;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this procedure.

```
Old_date = '27/06/2016';
New_date = Old_date.split('/');
New_date[2] = New_date[2].substring(2);
New_date = New_date.join('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reformat(dateStr)
{
dArr = dateStr.split("/");
return dArr[0]+ "/" +dArr[1]+ "/" +dArr[2].substring(2);     
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on real dates instead of strings:

```
function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);

    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]);
}

function formatDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2);

    return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
}
```

and then simply:

```
formatDate(parseDate('27/05/2016')); // returns "27/5/16"
```

Comment: This won't work because (a) JS dates use zero-based months, and (b) the OP wants two-digit day and month. (Also you should check how `.substr()`'s arguments work.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the input will always be in exactly that format then you can do it in one line with a simple regex-based string replace:

```
var output = input.replace(/..(..)$/,"$1");
```

Of course, you could make the regex more specific with `\d` for digits, but again if you know the input format is fixed `.` works fine to do a generic "remove the third- and fourth-last characters from any string".